# When change Activity, application has stopped

Tags: android, android-activity, crash

```
package com.example.dh.qrock;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button goManageList = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goManageList);

        goManageList.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), managelistActivity.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                        finish();

                        overridePendingTransition(R.xml.madefadein, R.xml.splashfadeout);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

when changing activity, the application has stopped. 
I use fade in and fade out.
How to fix that?

If you need another code, please comment here.

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.dh.qrock, PID: 4356
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dh.qrock/com.example.dh.qrock.managelistActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.dh.qrock.managelistActivity.onCreate(managelistActivity.java:19)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

here is the log.
It occurs NullPointException in button.
how to fix the NullPointException?
I changed Button.setOnclicklistener to View.onclickListener, But It doesn't work.

Comment: show logcat please .

Comment: Register your second activity in manifest file and remove that `finish` method.

Comment: Can you show logcat and animation xmls?

Comment: I add log. thanks.

Comment: can you share your xml file too?? java looks perfect.. Either the button id in xml has different name or managelistActivity is not included in manifest. Else it looks perfect.

Comment: @SubhechhuKhanal I add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the id of your `Button goManageList` if it exists in your `R.layout.activity_main`

Because you have this error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

It means that you are setting a setOnClickListener to a null object

Answer (score 0):

this because 
*overridePendingTransition(R.xml.madefadein, R.xml.splashfadeout);*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the context of the button in the intent like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), managelistActivity.class);
```

Give the context of the current activity like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(mainActivity.this, managelistActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

change Button.OnClickListener to View.OnClickListener

```
 goManageList.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener()
```

to

```
   goManageList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: I tried change button to view... but it doesn't work. thanks

Comment: I tried change button to view... but it doesn't work. thanks

Comment: post your activity_main.xml ?

Comment: you have sure Button have id is goManageList in activity_main.xml ?